# Find solutions to a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following system of linear equations with 5 variables, but I do not know how to find the solutions because there are only 3 equations. I have thought about using reduced row echelon forms, but it seems like there are no solutions?

$$−x_1 + x_3 − x_4 + x_5 = 1\\
x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 − 3x_5 = 3\\
2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 − 4x_5 = 2$$

to reduced row echelon form:

-1 0 1 -1 1 1

0 1 3 -1 -2 4

0 1 3 -1 -2 4

Comment: pick any $x_1$ and $x_2$ and then solve it as system of three unknowns with three equations. You will have infinite number of solutions.

Comment: I get that there are infinite solutions, but how do you find the general solution?

Comment: treat $x_1$ and $x_2$ as constants and solve the system. You will have $x_3, x_4, x_5$ expressed in terms of $x_1$  and $x_2$. That will be the general solution.

Comment: why do we treat x1 and x2 as constants? can't we choose x3, x4 or x5 instead?

Comment: it does not matter what two variables you choose as constants

Comment: I have done reduced row echelon form, and now I only have one equation:−x1+x3−x4+x5=1, what do I do next?? The second and third equations become the same after reduced row echelon form and u can cancel them.

Comment: Can you edit your questions to show reduced echelon form? If you have only two equations left, then three variables have to be treated as constants

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: so your general solution will be $$\begin{cases}
x_1=x_3-x_4+x_5-1 \\ 
x_2=4-3x_3+x_4+2x_5 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I figured and x3, x4 and x5 are constants

Comment: Yes, basically you pick any values for $x_3, x_4, x_5$ and calculate $x_1, x_2$ to get one of the solutions.